# Dividing a string into list according to the format given

Tags: python

I have a string like `"SAB_bARGS_D"` . What I want is that the string gets divided into list of characters but whenever there is a _ sign the next character gets appended to the previous one.

So the answer to above should be `['S','A','B_b','A','R','G','S_D']`

It can be done by using a for loop traversing through the list but is there an inbuilt function that I can use.....

Thanks a lot

---

Update

Hello all

Thanks to `Robert Rossney`,`aaronasterling` I got the required answer but I have an exactly similar question that I am going to ask here only...... Lets say that now my string has critaria that it can have a letter or a letter followed by _ and a number..... How can I seperate the string into list now...... The solutions suggested cannot be used now since S_10 would be seperated into S_1 and 0 ...... It would be helpful if someone can tell how to do so using RE.... Thanks a lot....

Comment: I would think that a `for` loop would be optimal here. A list comprehension solution is essentially going to have to make at least two passes and be terrible for readability.

Comment: Can anyone show it can be done using a for loop?

Comment: "SAB_b_ARGS_D" can this input possible?

Comment: No it cannot..... No letter is joined with _ on both sides

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know, I'll use regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = "[^_]_[^_]|[^_]"
>>> re.findall(pattern, "SAB_bARGS_D", re.IGNORECASE)
['S', 'A', 'B_b', 'A', 'R', 'G', 'S_D']
```

The pattern tries to match 3 characters in a row - non-underscore, underscore, non-underscore - and, failing that, tries to match a non-underscore character.

Comment: Hey your answer was what I wanted .... but I have a question to ask.... Is using re better than the for loop suggestion given below in terms of complexity ??? As In I am not aware what re uses to check the pattern so does it lead to decrease in performance as compared to using normal loops..... Its a general doubt not specifically in just this search.....

Comment: If you use `timeit`, you'll find that using `re.findall` in this case is marginally faster than using the function below - so marginally that I'd hazard a guess that the two are identical in complexity.  Well, processing complexity.  Code complexity is another matter.

Comment: Also, for your followup question, use the pattern `[a-z]_[0-9]+|[a-z]`.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use a `for` loop.

```
def a_split(inp_string):
    res = []
    if not inp_string: return res  # allows us to assume the string is nonempty

    # This avoids taking res[-1] when res is empty if the string starts with _
    # and simplifies the loop.
    inp = iter(inp_string)   
    last = next(inp)
    res.append(last)

    for c in inp:
        if '_' in (c, last): # might want to use (c == '_' or last == '_')
            res[-1] += c
        else:
            res.append(c)
        last = c
    return res
```

You will be able to get some performance gain my storing `res.append` in a local variable and referencing that directly instead of referencing a local variable, `res` and then performing an attribute lookup to get the `append` method.

If there is a string like `'a_b_c'` then it will not be split. No behavior was specified in this case but it wouldn't be to hard to modify it to do something else. Also a string like `'_ab'` will split into `['_a', 'b']` and similarly for `'ab_'`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression

```
>>> import re
>>> s="SAB_bARGS_D"
>>> re.findall("(.(?:_.)?)",s)
['S', 'A', 'B_b', 'A', 'R', 'G', 'S_D']
```